# Making large inputs small while performing operations

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I wanted to make this program run faster for large inputs

```
def count1(i,j,k,n):
    b = k
    while n > 0:
        b = i*b
        while b > j:
            b = b - j
        n = n - 1
    return b
```

So, after thinking about it, using mod operations came to mind. So, the above code was modified again

```
def count1(i,j,k,n):
    b = k
    while n > 0:
        b = ((i%j)*(b%j))%j
        while b > j:
            b = b - j
        n = n - 1
    return b
```

So after doing some testing, this implementation was indeed faster, however, it was not fast enough. Are there more ways of making large numbers small when performing operations on them such as this? Is there a way to optimize this code to make it run fast for very large inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Using cython or numba is probably the best way to improve the raw performance, have a look at the cython tutorial

Comment: I did look at it, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want a quicker implementation of the code above